# Category title override

Tags: magento2

I hope you are working well.

Magento 2.1.5

I need help how to override category h1 title with custom category attribute, without affecting product page title.

Thanks and appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a preference to override function `_prepareLayout()` of the block class

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Category\View.php
```

and when the `setPageTitle` function is called, use your custom attribute.